# Why do we need put_export and get_peek_export for uvm_tlm_fifo?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Section `12.2.8` of the IEEE UVM talks about the `uvm_tlm_fifo` classes. I was wondering why we need the exports `put_export` and `get_peek_export`?

The same `put` and `get` methods can be used on the fifo directly, why would I need to use the interface methods?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using TLM exports is removing dependancies when making connections. `put` and `get` of the uvm_tlm_fifo component are the method implementations, while the exports are just interfaces.

When you embed a fifo inside another component, you can call the implementations directly without making any connections as a shortcut. But if you want to have another component make a connection, the TLM principle abstracts away the existence of the FIFO and makes you connect to a generic put or get export.